# Angular two way data binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Thank you all guys. I will now select one detailed answer and close this up.

see the code below, it's fairly straight forward

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records track by record.id">
  <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td ng-repeat="(name, value) in record" ng-hide="name == 'id'">
    <portia-td value="{{value}}"></portia-td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the directive define

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  transclude: true, 
  scope: {
    value: '=' 
  },

  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.input = {show: false, value: $scope.value};
  },
  templateUrl: "td.html"
  }
```

Why this produce error? but when change the scope set back to '@', it works again.

Comment: `value="value"` instead of `value="{{value}}"` since you're binding to the model and not the interpolation of it.

Comment: thanks mate. you saved my day. but I have another question regarding the $watch. If I watched the "records" using Equality set to true. I change the "value" in the directive, seems like it's not notifying that "record" is changed in my recordCtrl.

Comment: "So I guess I should reuse the question to induce the new one.", no, don't do that. Now the answers posted to the previous question are showing as answers to the new question. The new question should be posted as a separate question and you should roll back the edits you made.

Comment: 1) Set the old question back. 2) Accept one of the answers. 3) Create a new post with the new question.

Comment: sorry guys, I will rectify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a bi-directional data binding, you need to use the `=`. Like this:

```
scope: {
  value: '=' 
}
```

And on the HTML:

```
<portia-td value="value"></portia-td>
```

When you use `"{{value}}"`, you are basically interpolating the value of the `value` property and passing it to the directive. This means angular will not be able to get the reference to create the bi-directional binding, all it will get is a value (string/number/etc...).

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Answer (score 1):

if you need to change the model outside the directive scope, you have to use the getter-setter model option. Check the following link, there is an example to update a value directly in the controller, outside the scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `{{value}}` when passing the value to the directive, that way you pass a reference and it's bi-directional.

Full plnkr example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rvY9A0DOEZpOEwOoy3xN?p=preview

```
<portia-td value="value"></portia-td>
```